# como juntar dos botones en el footer

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

estoy intentando juntar dos botones en el footer, pero estos no se adaptan a la pantalla, no son responsive, cuando la pantalla es pequeña los botones quedan fuera de esta, además no logro dejarlos juntos. mi codigo:

```
 <center><a style='position: absolute; color: #000; background: #fff; bottom:0; padding: 10px; width: 145px; text-align: center; border: solid 1px #000; margin-left: -195px; border-radius: 5px;'>LLAMAR<a style='position: absolute; color: #fff; background: #000; bottom:0; padding: 10px; width: 145px; text-align: center;  border: solid 1px #000; margin-left: -15px; border-radius: 5px;'>CHAT</a></a></center>
```

lo que quiero lograr:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Porque pones un elemento `<a>` dentro de un  elemento `<a>`?

Answer (score 2):

Para que sean responsive, el ancho debería ser en % y no fijo en px.
Sería buena práctica que utilices clases para definir el formato común de ambos, asi como tambien para lo particular.

```
<style>
.my-btn{
  position: absolute; bottom:0; padding: 10px; width: 40%; text-align: center; border: solid 1px #000;  border-radius: 5px;
}

.btn-llamar {
  color: #000; background: #fff;  margin-left: -195px;
}

btn-chat { 
  color: #fff; background: #000; margin-left: -15px;
}
</style>

<center>
<a class="my-btn btn-llamar">LLAMAR</a><a class="my-btn btn-chat" >CHAT</a></center>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hice un pequeño condigo para que te guíes; primero cree una capa con la clase **container** con un alto de **300px** para emular tu **body** y posicionar el **footer** en la parte de abajo de la página o en este caso en la capa con al clase **container**. Luego cree un **footer** para emular tu ejemplo donde dices que lo que tratas de hacer esta en el pie de tu página; y por último cree los dos botones los cuales les hice unas pequeñas modificaciones en el **css** para que sean **responsive**:

**1)** Le removi el atributo **position:absolute**.

**2)** A los dos botones el atributo **width** de los coloque por porcentaje para que se adapte mejor a cualquier resolución, por **px** se quedan estáticos.

**3)** A los dos botones les coloque la propiedad **display:inline-block;** para que sean tratados como texto y el **footer** los puedas centrar sin usar el **margin-left** y el **margin-right** que tu tenias; al footer le agregue la propiedas **text-alig:center** para que siempre centrara los dos botones automáticamente sin importar la resolución de la pantalla. Con esto te quitas la etiqueta `center` la cual ya esta **deprecated** o en desuso para html5.

**4)** A los botones les coloque una propiedad **font-size:3vw**, donde al colocar **vw** como unidad de medida le esta indicando que se adapte según la resolución de la pantalla.

Puedes ejecutar el código y para verlo funcionar al darle **ejecutar** hay una opción que se muestra después en la parte inferior derecha llamada **Página completa**, le das allí y ahí puedes probar minimizando el navegador para que veas como se va adaptando. Espero que se lo que andas buscando.

```css
.container{
  border:1px solid blue;
  height:300px;
  position:relative;
}

footer{
 border: 1px solid red;
 bottom:0px;
 position:absolute;
 text-align:center;
 width:100%;
}

.llamar,
.chat{
  border: solid 1px #000;
  border-radius: 5px;
  display:inline-block;
  font-size:3vw;
  padding:10px;
  text-align: center;
  width:20%;
}

.llamar{
  background-color:#fff;
  color:#000;
}

.chat{
  background-color:#000;
  color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <footer>
    <a class="llamar">LLAMAR</a>
    <a class="chat">CHAT</a>
  </footer>
</div>
```